# Wkhtmltoxsharp no cyrillic

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf with wkhtmltoxsharp wrapper. When I try to convert HTML to "pdf" it converts it, but only when the text is latin. I cannot convert  Cyrillic text, i get some strange characters.

Can you please help me, if you know any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested wkhtmltopdf with cyrilic, chinese and korean and they all work for me. Do you do the conversion on your desktop or on a server? It could be that the server does not have proper fonts the installed - that commonly causes this problem.

Also, it would help to see a little example of the content you are converting and the command (or piece of code) you use to convert.